# How to change the location of AVD to Android Studio?

Tags: linux, android-studio, fedora, android-virtual-device

**Hello, I'm using Linux. I can not install the Virtual Device Android.**
I click the button to create a virtual device. Then click Download. I get the following:

[image]

**After the next error, I decided to change the location of the Virtual Device.**
*I have a hard drive divided into 3 parts. The first is 410GB, the second is 50GB (root) and the third is 1GB.*